# Why am I not receiving any updates?

Tags: updates, 13.04

I recently upgraded from 12:10 to 13:04 on release day... and I haven't seen any updates... Surely there have been updates? Or has there??

I just can't believe that there have been no updates for an Ubuntu Release for four days?

Is this some kind of record or is there a problem with my computer??

[sources.list](http://pastebin.com/jz0xXiZ4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [raring-changes mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/raring-changes/2013-April/thread.html) you'll see that most of the uploads are to `raring-proposed`, which means they'll sit in -proposed being tested before being rolled out to users, so it'll likely be a few more days before updates start coming in.

At a minimum updates have to be in -proposed for at least 7 days before hitting -updates.

Comment: okay thanks that makes me feel better, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something wrong with my system and it was waiting to blow up or something....

Comment: Oh, it _is_ waiting to blow up. But I've said too much, I'll just shut up now.